# Help construct a query (schema provided)

Tags: sql, t-sql, schema

Here is the schema for the database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/omX60.png

Which company has the least entitlements?

Please tell me how wrong my answer is.

```
select top 1 companyName
serialNumber_tbl as sn, Entitlement_tbl as ent, Company_tbl as c
where sn.serialNumberId = ent.serialNumberId
and c.companyId = sn.companyId
order by count(distinct entitlementId) asc
group by companyName
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost right, I suppose. Missing the `FROM` keyword, and `GROUP BY` must come before `ORDER BY`.

```
select top 1 companyName
from serialNumber_tbl as sn, Entitlement_tbl as ent, Company_tbl as c
where sn.serialNumberId = ent.serialNumberId
and c.companyId = sn.companyId
group by companyName
order by count(distinct entitlementId) asc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1 companyName
**from** serialNumber_tbl as sn, Entitlement_tbl as ent, Company_tbl as c
where sn.serialNumberId = ent.serialNumberId
and c.companyId = sn.companyId
group by companyName
order by count(distinct entitlementId) asc
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have correctly pointed out the missing `from` keyword and the wrong order of the `group by` and `order by` clauses. There should be no problem about following the advice you got there.

One other thing is the syntax you are using to join the tables. Although technically not a mistake, it is considered outdated. The newer standard offers dedicated keywords for joining, which lets you separate your joining logic from your filtering-by-values logic, which previously, as per the older standard, had to be mixed in one clause, the `WHERE` clause.

Let me show this by rewriting the `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses for you, so you can see the difference. First, here's your current join logic implementation:

```
FROM serialNumber_tbl AS sn,
     Entitlement_tbl AS ent,
     Company_tbl AS c
WHERE sn.serialNumberId = ent.serialNumberId
  AND c.companyId = sn.companyId
```

Both conditions in the `WHERE` clause are join conditions. Here's how the same fragment of code changes when done with the newer syntax:

```
FROM serialNumber_tbl AS sn
  INNER JOIN Entitlement_tbl AS ent ON sn.serialNumberId = ent.serialNumberId
  INNER JOIN Company_tbl AS c ON c.companyId = sn.companyId
```

In this case the `WHERE` clause is gone entirely, of course, but you shouldn't have the wrong impression that it is always like that. Generally the `WHERE` clause remains valid and useful. If it contained some other conditions that were not part of the joining logic, they would retain there places in the `WHERE` clause. I'm talking about conditions like `ent.Date < '19900101' AND c.CompanyName NOT IN ('IBM', 'Microsoft')`.

Like I said earlier, with the older syntax, which you are using presently, that condition would be in one clause with the join conditions. In simpler cases, like yours, it might be overlooked without problems, but in more complex queries it could become an issue, if not a nightmare, in terms of maintainability. So the point is to get used to the newer syntax before you start writing such complex queries.